# Statistical test to use?

Tags: t-test, paired-data, control-group

I am currently conducting a quantitative experimental research wherein 2 groups will be my participants. The research aims to determine whether or not Code-Switching is an effective tool to achieve academic proficiency within the students.

Controlled Group - Will receive no treatment and will be simply taught in pure english; with respect to the given Medium of Instruction on such subject

Experimental Group - Will be taught in means of Code-Switching(shifting from one lang. to another)

I will be conducting a pre-test before the lecture (around 1-2 weeks) and a post-test will also be conducted after such lecture to measure which of the two groups understood the lesson better.

I've been searching for tests and I've found the following: 
-two sample t-test
-log linear analysis
-Aspin-Welch Unequal-Variance test

Please help me in finding the best test to use to get accurate and reliable results.